# Yolo object detection result based blink led

Tags: signals, gpio, yolov8, jetson-xavier

I want to ask a question.we are developing a project about classification of some material  depend on a colors. We used YOLO v8.  After that we have some problem about generating signals with GPIO. We want to at least tree pin deploy on Jetson Xavier Nx based on yolov8 model object detection results (for example apple: pin11, orange: pin13 etc.) How ve write python code for this process ?

I found several different codes. But I couldn't find where to paste it in yolov8... Python_rs.py or detect.py.